# Best way to join and sort small-ish, already sorted lists into one big list?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, algorithm, list, sorting

I have a list (array, not linked list) of sorted objects. It is not a long list: anywhere from 3 to 20 elements, though most of the time it would probably be around the shorter end. This list, and all others, will come from HTTP requests. There will be about 30-50 requests, each producing an array of the same number of elements. The way my code works now is that the requests are synchronous. I realize this is not efficient, and will probably be changed to some multi-threading soon, but for now I'm still in the initial stages. What would be the best way to join all these arrays into one big, sorted array? Would it be as each array is returned from the request and appended to the resulting array? Or maybe sorted once all requests are done? Since there's not that many elements, relatively speaking, does it even matter? Would multi-threading make a difference on the solution?

I am not sure if it makes any difference that the arrays will be similar in the values that they hold. For example:
[100,200,300], [99, 105, 290], [115,215, 280]

Comment: Do the numbers to be sorted are within  some relatively small range?

Comment: From the constraints you have given, taking the worst case, there are `(20 x 50)` elements at max, when all requests are done. This is 1000 elements. I'd say, instead of any comparing and all while merging the lists, simply merge all arrays and sort at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to merge multiple sorted lists into a single list is to do a [k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms).

Start with an empty priority queue, usually a min-heap if you're sorting in ascending order, and push the first item from each of the lists onto the heap. The structure you store in the heap must have the value (i.e. the number) and also a reference to the list it came from. Then:

1. Pop the first item from the heap and add its value to your output.
2. Take the next item from the list that contained the item you just popped from the heap, and add it to the heap.
3. Continue until the heap is empty.

In short, the min-heap always has one item from each of the lists, and the lowest of those items is always the first item on the heap. Since the individual lists are in order to begin with, this guarantees that the item at the top of the heap is always the smallest remaining item in all lists, so it's the one that gets output next.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few sensible approaches, that can be tried and then measured for relative performance.

Since the number of elements to sort is small, the constant factors in the implementation the sorting algorithm would have relatively bigger impact on the overall performance, compared to the algorithm's asymptotic complexity.

I'd collect all the individual ranges in one array and sort it once all the requests are done; this will keep the array hot in cache, while you're sorting, instead of interleaving many sorts with random other processing.

If the numbers to sort are within a small range, sort them via **counting sort**; the extra `O(n)` memory needed should not be an issue, since `n` is at most 1000.

Otherwise, as the sequence consist of multiple sorted ranges, an **insertion sort** is likely to perform well, the inner loop is expected to not loop many times and when it does loop, the conditional inside ought to have good branch prediction characteristics.

All that said, for such a small number of elements, it's very likely that it does not matter what approach you choose, so just collect all the elements in an array and use your system's library sort function.