# Complexity of merging k sorted list

Tags: c++, algorithm

The problem is merging k sorted lists to one sorted list.
I've already finished three kinds of solutions.
First is dichotomy, like this:

```
ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists) 
{
    if(lists.size()==0) return NULL;
    return mergeKLists(lists,0,lists.size()-1);
}

ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists,int start,int end) 
{
    if(start==end) return lists[start];
    ListNode *l1=mergeKLists(lists,start,(start+end)/2);
    ListNode *l2=mergeKLists(lists,(start+end)/2+1,end);
    return merge2Lists(l1,l2);
}
```

The complexity is about O(nklogk)=(2n*k/2+4n*k/4+.....nk*k/k)

Second,use heap,like this:

```
static bool heapComp(ListNode* a, ListNode* b) {
        return a->val > b->val;
}
ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists) { //make_heap
    ListNode head(0);
    ListNode *curNode = &head;
    vector<ListNode*> v;   
    for(int i =0; i<lists.size(); i++){
        if(lists[i]) v.push_back(lists[i]);
    }
    make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), heapComp); //vector -> heap data strcture

    while(v.size()>0){
        curNode->next=v.front();
        pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), heapComp); 
        v.pop_back(); 
        curNode = curNode->next;
        if(curNode->next) {
            v.push_back(curNode->next); 
            push_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), heapComp);
        }
    }
    return head.next;
}
```

The complexity is about O(nklogk),because refine heap needs logk, and we need to do this for nk times.

The third method is what I am confused of.I take the idea of Haffman Three,each time I take two shortest lists and do the merge,like this:

```
struct Node{
  ListNode* node;
  int length;
  Node(ListNode *n,int x){
      node=n;
      length=x;
  }
};
bool compare(Node l1,Node l2)
{
    return l1.length>l2.length;
}
ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists) 
{
        vector<Node> newlists;
        if(lists.empty()) return NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<lists.size();i++)
            newlists.push_back(Node(lists[i],length(lists[i])));
        make_heap(newlists.begin(),newlists.end(),compare);
        while(newlists.size()!=1)
        {
            Node p=newlists.front();
            pop_heap (newlists.begin(),newlists.end(),compare);
            Node q=newlists.front();
            newlists.pop_back();
            pop_heap (newlists.begin(),newlists.end(),compare);
            newlists.pop_back();
            newlists.push_back(Node(merge2Lists(p.node,q.node),p.length+q.length));
            push_heap (newlists.begin(),newlists.end(),compare);
        }
        return newlists[0].node;
}
```

I think the complexity is about O(nklogk+klogk),because it needs O(klogk) for extra pop_heap compared to the first method.

However,if the lengths of k lists vary greatly. It is obviously that the third method is superior to the first. For example, lists with lengths(20,50,40),The first needs to do 20+50+70+40=180 comparisons,while the third only needs 20+40+60+50=170 comparisons.

Is this a contradiction?

Am I doing the correct computation for the complexity of these methods?

Can anyone explain the complexity of these methods if the lengths of lists vary greatly ?

Comment: Here is a useful youtube video that breaks down both the space and time complexity of a merge sort algorithm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nlPxaC2lTw. This may help you to break down your specific problem even more.

Comment: Regular merge (the same you find in mergesort) will be linear here

Comment: The general worst case scenario of the merge sort if N is large should be Big O :  (n log n). You can drop constants and lower exponential orders for the lower bounds.

Comment: Merge of k sorted lists is O(n log k). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms#Direct_K-Way_Merge.

Comment: @JimMischel wiki takes output size as n, this n is equal to my nk here.

Comment: So you have `k` sorted lists, each of which contains `n` items?

Comment: Your second solution is really nothing but a merge sort with complexity O(n log n), where `n` is the combined total number of items in all lists. The k-way merge is O(n log k), where `k` is the number of lists and `n` is the total number of items across all lists. The Wikipedia article I linked shows how that's done. I explain it more simply in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36938261/56778. The key is that your heap only contains `k` items.

Comment: Correction: the second example is a heap sort, not a merge sort.

Comment: Just a small correction - O(nklogk+klogk) =  O(n(klogk+1)) =  O(nklogk)